# Limit fetch size of Net::HTTP.request_get

Tags: ruby, http, limit

I want to fetch some content from a webserver using Net:HTTP, like this:

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/index.html')
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.get('/index.html')
}
puts res.body
```

But I need to limit the get to the first 5kb to reduce the network traffic. How do I do this?

Comment: Correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120350/how-to-download-via-http-only-piece-of-big-file-with-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when using Net::HTTP but using OpenURI i usually do the following:

```
require 'open-uri'

resource = open('http://google.com')

resource.read( 5120 ) 
=> # reads first 5120 characters, which i'm assuming would be 5KB.
```

hope this helps.

Comment: open-uri's open(url) fetches everything. This is a wrong answer considering his goal is reducing network traffic.