# Converting python script to ruby (downloading part of a file)

Tags: ruby

I've been at this for a couple of day, and am having no luck at all. Despite reading over [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http-using-ruby) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120350/how-to-download-via-http-only-piece-of-big-file-with-ruby) posts, I can't seem to rewrite this little python script I did up in ruby.

```
clean_link = link['href'].replace(' ', '%20')
mp3file = urllib2.urlopen(clean_link)
output = open('temp.mp3','wb')
output.write(mp3file.read(2000))
output.close()
```

I've been looking at using `open-uri` and `net/http` to do the same in ruby, but keep hitting a url redirect issue. So far I have

```
clean_link = link.attributes['href'].gsub(' ', '%20')
link_pieces = clean_link.scan(/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/]+?)(\/.*?\.mp3)/)

host = link_pieces[0][0]
path = link_pieces[0][1] 

Net::HTTP.start(host) do |http|
    resp = http.get(path)
    open("temp.mp3", "wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
    end
end
```

Is there a simpler way to do this in ruby? Also, as with the python script, is there a way to only download part of the file?

EDIT: progress updated

Answer (score 1):

see [here](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTPResponse.html#M000706) & [here](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html)

```
http.request_get('/index.html') {|res|
  size = 0
  res.read_body do |chunk|
     size += chunk.size
     # do some processing
     break if size >= 2000
  end
}
```

but you can't control chunk sizes here

Comment: Hi Zed, this is the issue that keeps popping up with a http->https redirect `http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2027`

Comment: thanks zed. What do the chunks add to in order to check how much has been read?