# Fast way to get remote image dimensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, open-uri

I'm using the imagesize gem to check the sizes of remote images and then only push images that are big enough into an array.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'image_size'
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
images = []
forcenocache = Time.now.to_i # No cache because jquery load event doesn't fire for cached images
data.css("img").each do |image|
  image_path = URI.join(site, URI.encode(image[:src]))
  open(image_path, "rb") do |fh|
    image_size = ImageSize.new(fh.read).get_size()
    unless image_size[0] < 200 || image_size[1] < 100
      image_element = "<img src=\"#{image_path}?#{forcenocache}\">"
      images.push(image_element)
    end
  end
end
```

I tried using JS on the front-end to check image dimensions but there seems to be a browser limit to how many images can be loaded at once.

Doing it with imagesize is much slower than using JS. Any better and faster ways to do this?

Comment: My recommendations are - at first find all image links on a page and filter out duplicates.  Probably, loading only piece of image will work (few first kilobytes) - try this.  Also, you may use threads to check multiple images in parallel.  Probably, there are some img tags on a page with dimensions set.

Comment: How would one go about reading first n kilobytes of the image to get the size using open-uri?

Comment: here is link to my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120350/how-to-download-via-http-only-piece-of-big-file-with-ruby

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think this gem does what you want https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage

> FastImage finds the size or type of an
>   image given its uri by fetching as
>   little as needed

Comment: I just want to say... I stumbled upon this answer, and therefor, this gem.  It's incredible.  +1 +1 +1 +1 +1!!!