# How can I QUICKLY get a string from one of the first couple lines of a long CSV at a remote URL?

Tags: ruby, csv, open-uri

I'm working on an assignment where I retrieve several stock prices from online, using Yahoo's stock price system. Unfortunately, the [Yahoo API](http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=TICKER_SYMBOL) I'm required to use  returns a .csv file that apparently contains a line for every single day that stock has been traded, which is at least 5 thousand lines for the stocks I'm working with, and over 10 thousand lines for some of them ([example](http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=XOM)).

I only care about the *current* price, though, which is in the second line.

I'm currently doing this:

```
require 'open-uri'
def get_ticker_price(stock)
   open("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=#{stock}") do |io|
      io.read.split(',')[10].to_f
   end
end
```

…but it's **really** slow.

1. Is all the delay coming from getting the file, or is there some from the way I'm handling it? Is `io.read` reading the entire file?
2. Is there a way to download only the first couple lines from the Yahoo CSV file?
3. If the answers to questions 1 & 2 don't render this one irrelevant, is there a better way to process it that doesn't require looking at the entire file (assuming that's what `io.read` is doing)?

Comment: This sounds suspicously like:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120350/how-to-download-via-http-only-piece-of-big-file-with-ruby

Comment: The way the open command seems to work is to firstly save the downloaded webpage to a temp file, then pass that Tempfile IO object to the given block. Ie `open("http://...") { |io| puts File.read(io.path) }` outputs the contents of the downloaded webpage. So the `open` method downloads the entire file before it even gets to your block. Unfortunately I don't know how to partly download a file (never needed to do that before), so I can't answer 2 or 3, however I'm pretty sure you won't be able to use `open` to do this.

Comment: You can reduce the file size by specifying last trade date in the query string, if you use the quotes service. 

example:
    http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MO&f=snd1l1yr

If you can use this other service, more info here: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/yahoo-finance-hidden-api/

Comment: actually, i found a better reference for the service you are using. Here is example of getting just todays data: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MO&a=06&b=13&c=2012&d=6&e=13&f=2012&g=d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use query string parameters to reduce the data to the current date, by using date range parameters.

example for MO on 7/13/2012: (start/end month starts w/ a zero-index, { 00 - 11 } ).

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MO&a=06&b=13&c=2012&d=6&e=13&f=2012&g=d

api description here:
http://etraderzone.com/free-scripts/47-historical-quotes-yahoo.html

Comment: Thanks, Tim! This solved my problem, but I'm going to hold off on accepting it for a day or two to see if anyone else can come up with a Ruby way of doing it, since that was *technically* the question asked. :)

Comment: The first comment to your question links to another SO question where that is answered.

Comment: @LarsHaugseth: Both of the answers in that question entail low-level socket manipulation, which, as the author of one of the answers pointed out, isn't really a very Ruby way to solve the problem. Since that question is 3 years old, I figured it might be worth waiting a bit to see if there's a cleaner solution available now (several Ruby versions later).

Comment: Looks like the server on which the service is running does not support the "Range" HTTP request header, so you're probably out of luck doing this with pure HTTP libraries.