# Ruby CSV::Table read first line

Tags: ruby, csv

I am taking a symbol and requesting Yahoo Finance web service to get the data for that symbol(company).

It is returning a `CSV::Table` when I do the following operation:

```
symbols_list.each{|symbol| 
                table= CSV.parse open("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=#{URI.encode(symbol)}").read, :headers=>true, :converters=>:numeric
```

The output is a `CSV::Table` with headers for each row. However, I want to extract only the first row from the results and get a part of that row.

I have tried using `table.push` but it is printing up all the rows instead of one.

Comment: What do you mean by 'only the first row" and "part of that row"? Have you tried opening up your terminal and seeing what values you can get from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get, messing around on the command line:

```
[16] pry(main)> table= CSV.parse open("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG").read, :headers=>true, :converters=>:numeric
=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:2297>
[17] pry(main)> table.first
=> #<CSV::Row "Date":"2013-10-01" "Open":880.25 "High":887.67 "Low":880.05 "Close":887.0 "Volume":1684800 "Adj Close":887.0>
[18] pry(main)> table.first.first
=> ["Date", "2013-10-01"]
```

To get the closing price:

```
[23] pry(main)> table.first["Close"]
=> 887.0
```

Comment: I want to extract the closing price i.e the "Close" from the first row. How should I?

Comment: That's just the answer I was going to give! As an additional note, [this previous Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497722/how-can-i-quickly-get-a-string-from-one-of-the-first-couple-lines-of-a-long-csv?rq=1) indicates how to just query today's data so you don't have to download thousands of lines for each ticker symbol.

Comment: Here's what rubocop has to say: `The use of Kernel#open is a serious security risk.` What is the proper way to read a csv file into a CSV::Table?

Comment: Here's what I used: `table = CSV.table('filepath.csv', headers: true)`